# Почему я не получаю URI сервера от переменной $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']??? Как отлаживать код с использованием сервера?

Tags: php, apache

Есть простая функция `explode(string $separator, string $string, int $limit = PHP_INT_MAX): array`. Как я понял из документации она разбивает полученную строку на массив строк разделенных каким-либо знаком.

Также есть переменная $_SERVER которая хранит информацию о сервере и среде исполнения.

Тут я проверил что функция `explode()` работает:

```
<?php
    $path = explode('/', 'http://test');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            <?php 
                echo var_dump($path);
            ?>
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Вот результат [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут я вместо `http://test` вставляю `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`:

```
<?php
    $path = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            <?php 
                echo var_dump($path);
            ?>
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Вот что я получаю: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходя из увиденного я делаю вывод что я просто не получаю ничего от сервера через переменную `$_SERVER`.

Вопроса два

1. Как я могу получить значение переменной `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`? Без этого я не могу понять как на практике реальзовать MVC паттерн.
2. Есть ли способ отлаживать код используя еще и ресурсы веб-сервера? И если есть - то какой? Проблема в том что когда я запускаю код на отладку через командную строку, то запускается только сам код `php`. И когда этот же код содержит в себе какие-то аргументы или функции направленные на работу с сервером то в лучшем случае я получаю ошибку - так как сам код никак не работает с сервером. Мне бы иметь какую нибудь возможность проходить пошагово по коду попутно получая результаты работы `apache` чтобы лучше понимать где конкретно находится ошибка.

Заранее спасибо)

Ответ для комментария Alexey Ten

```
array(32) { 
["HTTP_HOST"]=> string(4) "test" 
["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=> string(10) "keep-alive" ["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"]=> string(9) "max-age=0"
["HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS"]=> string(1) "1" 
["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=> string(101) "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 
["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=> string(135) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9" 
["HTTP_REFERER"]=> string(12) "http://test/" 
["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=> string(13) "gzip, deflate" 
["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=> string(65) "ru,ru-RU;q=0.9,ja-JP;q=0.8,ja;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.5,la;q=0.4" 
["PATH"]=> string(70) "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin" 
["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=> string(65) "

Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at test Port 80
" 
["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=> string(22) "Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)" 
["SERVER_NAME"]=> string(4) "test" 
["SERVER_ADDR"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.2" 
["SERVER_PORT"]=> string(2) "80" 
["REMOTE_ADDR"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.1" 
["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(13) "/var/www/html" 
["REQUEST_SCHEME"]=> string(4) "http" 
["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]=> string(0) "" 
["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(13) "/var/www/html" 
["SERVER_ADMIN"]=> string(14) "webmaster@test" 
["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=> string(23) "/var/www/html/index.php" 
["REMOTE_PORT"]=> string(5) "44508" 
["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=> string(7) "CGI/1.1" 
["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=> string(8) "HTTP/1.1" 
["REQUEST_METHOD"]=> string(3) "GET" 
["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(0) "" 
["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(1) "/" 
["SCRIPT_NAME"]=> string(10) "/index.php" 
["PHP_SELF"]=> string(10) "/index.php" 
["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]=> float(1669272016.449686) 
["REQUEST_TIME"]=> int(1669272016) }
```

Comment: Я бы для начала посмотрел на `var_dump($_SERVER)`

Comment: "Проблема в том что когда я запускаю код на отладку через командную строку"  --- в таком случае никаких REQUEST_URI  быть не может.....это же консоль

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Это то я понимаю. А есть ли способ получать информацию и с сервера во время отладки? Тот же самый $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: C сервера да (если смотреть в отладку и данные $_SERVER - там всё есть),  конкретно REQUEST_URI - нет. это же консоль, какой там uri?   отладить MVC приложение, тем не менее, с запуска с консоли - можно, для этого долна быть прописана нормальная маршрутизация

Comment: Просто если вопрос в том, можно ли по MVC приложению ходить во время отладки, запустив приложение из консоли - ответ: можно.  Если взять, например, фреймворк *Yii2* - там есть и веб приложение и консольное, отладка работает и там и там. Как обстоят дела например у самопального MVC - ну это другой вопрос

Comment: @AlexeyTen Результат добавил в вопрос. Получается я могу использовать вместо 'REQUEST_URI' - 'HTTP_REFERER'? или это уже будет говнокод?

Comment: Нет, не можешь, это разные вещи.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский "отладить MVC приложение, тем не менее, с запуска с консоли - можно, для этого долна быть прописана нормальная маршрутизация" --- Приведете пример если не затруднит - хотя бы абстрактно.

Comment: @u_mulder выходит чтобы находить ошибки подобного рода нужно смотреть только на то что выводит `var_dump($_SERVER)` и пытаться это сопоставить с кодом?

Comment: @ReijiAkkerman возьмите Yii2 basic, настройте его в основном виде, откройте проект в phpstorm, при этом не помещая папку vendor  в exluded, чтобы можно было там лазить в дебаге, поставьте точку останова в файле index.php на строке `(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();` и походите посмотрите куда он заходит и что где парсит... с этим придётся посидеть поразбираться, но там можно для себя многое понять, кмк. основные классы будут задействованы это Request, UrlManager и Application   из папок base/web/console

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Благодарю))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по дампу **$_SERVER** вы открываете корневую страницу сайта. Т.е. у вас ссылка вида **http://test/** А **REQUEST_URI** это грубо говоря часть ссылки после домена. В вашем случае это просто "/"

И ваш скрипт отрабатывает корректно. Если вы укажите ссылку вида "http://test/index.php** то в **REQUEST_URI** будет "index.php" и тогда ваш скрипт отработает чуть более корректно.